# jQuery.data parsing string like 10E6 as int (10000000)

Tags: jquery

Given an element like this `<a data-test="10E6">` jQuery interprets the value as an integer in scientific notaion rather than a string as intended when I do `elem.data('test')`

Given that this is happening in a fairly large application I'm exploring my options for changing this behavior without having to switch to using `elem.attr('data-test')` everywhere that this may happen.

Since jQuery uses $.isNaN internally before trying to parse the value as a float I could override isNaN adding the regex `^[E\d]+$` like so:

```
$.isNaN = function( obj ) {
    return obj == null || !$.rdigit.test( obj ) || /E/.test( obj ) || isNaN( obj );
}
```

or override the much more complex `$.data`

Does anyone have a better plan?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of `.data()` itself, the jQuery developers tell you to use `.attr()` to retrieve the value without coercing it. I'd imagine overriding the internals that jQuery is using would be a more detrimental problem than simply switching to the appropriate method.

Comment: Thanks. Just going to have to bite the bullet and comb through the code to make all the changes.

Comment: I couldn't find anything official from the devs, but I have been using `.attr()` for this (I have customers naming parts "01" and they expect the leading zeroes, which vary in number(!) to be preserved) and it's been working as expected. It seems like a safe thing to do, because data attributes are just attributes, and attr shouldn't care.